# Spark. ~100 million rows. Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: apache-spark

(This is with Spark 2.0 running on a small three machine Amazon EMR cluster)

I have a PySpark job that loads some large text files into a Spark RDD, does count() which successfully returns 158,598,155.

Then the job parses each row into a pyspark.sql.Row instance, builds a DataFrame, and does another count. This second count() on the DataFrame causes an exception in Spark internal code `Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE`. This works with smaller volumes of data. Can someone explain why/how this would happen?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 22 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 22.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 77, ip-172-31-97-24.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1287)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalValues(BlockManager.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

PySpark code:

```
raw_rdd = spark_context.textFile(full_source_path)

# DEBUG: This call to count() is expensive
# This count succeeds and returns 158,598,155
logger.info("raw_rdd count = %d", raw_rdd.count())
logger.info("completed getting raw_rdd count!!!!!!!")

row_rdd = raw_rdd.map(row_parse_function).filter(bool)
data_frame = spark_sql_context.createDataFrame(row_rdd, MySchemaStructType)

data_frame.cache()
# This will trigger the Spark internal error
logger.info("row count = %d", data_frame.count())
```

Comment: What is the second `counts()`'s expected result?

Comment: Please share the snippet in which the error occurs.

Comment: @gsamaras, basically the same as the first count.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes not from the `data_frame.count()` itself but rather because parsing the rows via `row_parse_function` yields some integers which don't fit into the specified integer type in `MySchemaStructType`.

Try to increase the integer types in your schema to `pyspark.sql.types.LongType()` or alternatively let spark infer the types by omitting the schema (this however can slow down the evaluation).

Comment: Now, the `row_parse_function` was definitely checking for out of bound values. The exception is happening in `FileChannelImpl.map` which wouldn't make sense with an out of range parsing error.

Comment: @clay Could you post `row_parse_function` and `MySchemaStructType`?